# What *is* a salt formula, really?

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to work through the Salt Formulas documentation and seem to be having a fundamental misunderstanding of what a salt formula really is.

*Understandably, this question may seem like a duplicate of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48335236/4614134) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25405425/4614134), but due to my failing to grasp the basic concepts I'm also struggling to make use of the answers to these questions.*

I *thought*, that a salt formula is basically just a package that implements extra functions, a lot like

```
#include <string.h>
```

in C, or

```
import numpy as np
```

in Python. Thus, I thought, I could download the [`salt-formula-linux`](https://github.com/salt-formulas/salt-formula-linux) to `/srv/formulas/salt-formula-linux/`, add that to `file_roots`, restart the master (all as per the [docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/conventions/formulas.html#adding-a-formula-directory-manually)), and then write a file like `swapoff.sls` containing

```
disable_swap:
  linux:
    storage:
      swap:
        file:
          enabled: False
```

(the above is somewhat similar to the examples in the repo's root) in hope that the formula would then handle removing the swap entry from `/etc/fstab` and running `swapoff -a` for me. Needless to say, this didn't work, clearly because I'm not understanding what a salt formula is meant to be.

**So, what is a salt formula and how do I use it? Can I make use of it as a library of functions too?**

Comment: salt formula I have not heard of that before

Answer (score 1):

This answer might not be fully correct in all technicalities, but this is what solved my problem.

A salt formula is *not* a library of functions. It is, rather, a collection of state files. While often a state file can be very simple, such as some of my user defined

```
--> top.sls <--
base:
  '*':
    - docker

--> docker.sls <--
install_docker_1703:
  pkgrepo.managed:
    # stuff
  pkg.installed:
    - name: docker-ce
```

creating a state file like

```
--> swapoff.sls <--
disable_swap:
  linux.storage.swap: # and so on
```

is, perhaps, not the way to go. Well, at least, maybe not for a beginner with lacking knowledge.

Instead, add an item to `top.sls`:

```
    - linux.storage.swap
```

This is not enough, however. Most formulas (or the state files within them, if you will) are highly parametrizable, i.e. they're full of placeholders with variable names, such as `{{ swap.device }}`. If there's nothing to fill this gap, the state fill will not be able to do anything. These gaps are filled from **pillars**.

All that remains, is to create a file like `swap.sls` in `/srv/pillar/` that would contain something like (as per the examples of that formula)

```
linux:
  storage:
    enabled: true
    swap:
      file:
        enabled: true
        engine: file
        device: /swapfile
        size: 1024
```

and also `/srv/pillar/top.sls` with

```
base:
  '*':
    - swap
```

Perhaps `/srv/pillar` should also be included in `pillar_roots` in `/etc/salt/master`.

So now `/srv/salt/top.sls` runs `/srv/formulas/salt-formula-linux/linux/storage/swap.sls` which using the guidance of `/srv/pillar/top.sls` pulls some parameters from `/srv/pillar/swap.sls` and enables a swapfile.